# rsync fails/hangs when copying from a Linux ext4 to a FreeBSD ZFS (via SSH)

Tags: rsync, nfs, acl, zfs

When I try to copy directories from an ext4 on Linux to a ZFS on FreeBSD (via SSH), `rsync` immediately fails without copying anything:

```
# rsync -haxHAX /mnt/source/ root@lethe:/mnt/dest/ -vvv
opening connection using: ssh -l root lethe rsync --server -vvvlHogDtpAXrxe.iLs . /mnt/dest/  (9 args)
sending incremental file list
[…]
server_recv(2) starting pid=83765
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (38 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=226): about to call exit(12)
```

When I try to copy a single file instead, `rsync` "gets stuck" and hangs indefinitely, also without copying anything:

```
# rsync -haxHAX /mnt/source/test.txt root@lethe:/mnt/dest/test.txt -vvv
opening connection using: ssh -l root lethe rsync --server -vvvlHogDtpAXrxe.iLs . /mnt/dest/test.txt  (9 args)
sending incremental file list
[sender] make_file(test.txt,*,0)
send_file_list done
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=83944
recv_file_name(test.txt)
[ hangs indefinitely ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ext4 uses [POSIX ACLs](http://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/ACLs#POSIX_ACLs) (when they are explicitly enabled via the `acl` mount option).
ZFS uses [NFSv4 ACLs](http://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/ACLs#NFSv4_and_Windows_ACLs) (at least on FreeBSD).

As the `rsync` man page states:

```
-A, --acls
  The source and destination systems must have compatible ACL entries for
  this option to work properly.
```

Without the `-A` option, the transfer works without any problems.